How can I angle a toilet waste pipe when I have two toilets?
This question is related to Can you run two toilets on the same horizontal soil/waste pipe?, but is a different question.
Our house used to have only one toilet, with a waste pipe running downhill by a couple of degrees until it exited the wall of the house, where it branched into a vertical pipe.
Then at some point, someone added another toilet, and to make the pipe work easier, changed the pipe to be horizontal.

Then we bought the house. We noticed that the toilets don't flush that well, the water takes a bit of time to drain out of the bowl. We asked a plumber, and he thinks it's because the waste pipe is horizontal, and not angled, as it should be.
I can understand why they made it horizontal. I can see that it would be very difficult joining toilet 2 to a waste pipe that was a couple of inches lower.

What are my options here?
Option 1: Use an offset fitting, plus a branch. This would work, but the offset would push the toilet away from the wall a couple of inches, which I would prefer not to do, since it's a very small bathroom.
Option 2: Is there such a thing as an offset branch piece, to allow Toilet 2 to connect to the lower pipe?
Is there another option?
Note: There is very little space available around Toilet 2. There is no room to run two separate pipes.

@Ecnerwal the diagrams weren't clear to me either until I realized the OP is in the UK where the waste exit from the toilet typically comes out the back, not out the bottom like it typically does for US toilets. So the diagrams are looking at the back of the toilets, not down from above.

@Ecnerwal - I have changed the diagrams. I hope they are clearer.

Without knowing the framing, it would be better if each toilet had an elbow down to vertical before connecting to the trunk, i.e. the trunk would be better located below the toilet outlet.

@Huesmann - ~Yes, that would definitely be preferable. I'm not sure if it's possible though, I'll have to take up the floor and see what's underneath.

The wye for the second toilet is turned up towards the second toilet, and another angled fitting (one of the smaller angles, typically) is placed into it, with the rotation of the second and the wye adjusted to meet the toilet outlet.
If it's built as illustrated that may require moving the line, as there's no space as shown. But you'll be moving the line somewhat anyway to correct the slope.
I don't know what the UK allows, but under IPC plumbing code that configuration would require a vent near toilet 1. The permissible unvented connection to a stack with vent is fairly short, and for only 1 toilet on the line. This looks too long even for the one.

That's what I had hoped to do, but there's just no room for an angled fitting to connect the toilet to the wye. I'm not sure how I can get a vent near toilet 1 as it's in the middle of the house. Toilet 2 is by an external wall.

If toilet 2 is by an external wall, and you are in the UK, I think (hope?) perhaps the stack is outside?  So can you instead put the toilet 2 drain separately through the wall and connect to the stack a little lower?

@jay613 modern UK houses often have internal stacks, boxed in but quite accessible

Replace the bowl of toilet 2 with a right-hand p-trap type and run two separate horizontal drains.
A right hand p trap has the pipe connection to the side of the toilet bowl instead of to the back  thus it can have a separate lateral pipe and separate connection to the stack.

Thanks. I'm not sure what you mean. Can you draw a diagram?

If the distance between the toilets is not very far you might be able to raise Toilet 1 onto a small plinth so that the waste pipe hits Toilet 2 at the correct height.  The further apart they are, however, the greater the height required so unless they are close together this suggestion won't work.

Thanks. That's certainly a possibility. I'll consider it, but I would much rather have a simpler solution if there is one.

If the outlets are at the same height-above-sea-level, the pipe between them must by definition be horizontal so I'm struggling to find an alternative solution.  Interesting problem though.

You can support up to 3 toilets on a 3" line and 4 toilets on a 4" (there are other rules).    But you can for sure have two toilets on a 3" line and just make sure the slope is 1/4" down per foot.   You need 3" combos for each connection to the "horizontal" drain.

Thank you, but this question is not about the number of toilets that I can have on a pipe. It's about how I can connect the second toilet, given that the pipe should have dropped slightly once is reaches the second toilet.

@Rocketmagnet - I said you need 3" combos on each toilet.   Revise your drawing with these - https://www.lowes.com/pd/Charlotte-Pipe-3-in-x-3-in-dia-45-Degree-PVC-Schedule-40-Hub-Combo-Wye-Fitting/3132837?cm_mmc=shp--c--prd--plb--ggl--CRP_SHP_LIA_PLB_Online_E-F--3132837--local--0-_-0&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAjwx-CyBhAqEiwAeOcTdceXZH9haKiqeqDE860E2KT6U9qbTjD0cSRAGM7cok2TupBobbC96hoC1k4QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds - and yes your first toilet gets one too...   You just cap it and its a clean out.
